# Undefined modules when switching to a newer version of android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm attempting to upgrade from ndk-r11c to ndk-r14. When I run r14, I get an error

> Android NDK: Module myJNI depends on modules: png jpeg log

In my Android make:
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := png jpeg log

Comment: Is that error message correct? Are you sure it doesn't say "depends on **undefined** modules"?

Comment: yes, sorry. "undefined modules"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you didn't copy the full error message and it actually said "depends on **undefined** modules", check the [release notes](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r14):

> Module builds will now fail if they have any missing dependencies. To revert to the old behavior, set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true. See https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/208.

`liblog` shouldn't be in `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`. You want `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog` instead. Although, actually, if this warning is firing but your project was building you're not using it anyway.

`libjpeg` and `libpng` don't appear to be defined in your project. Just remove them since they can't have been used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Met similar error with OpenCV Android SDK 3.1 which missing opencv_legacy module

```
/home/jenkins/android-ndk-r15c/build/core/build-binary.mk:688: Android NDK: Module TestProject depends on undefined modules: opencv_legacy
```

Add the following line to the src/main/jni/Application.mk resolve the problem, thanks @Dan Albert

```
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true
```

Comment: In another project, even add the above line,  still showing the same error: `Android NDK: Module ProjectTest2 depends on undefined modules: opencv_legacy`. Then we found `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` need to be changed from 4.8 to 4.9, then we can build without error.  Changed `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8` to `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9`

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, but for a different reason.

The build environment was hosted on Windows, and the project being build was in a deep directory. Due to Windows path size limitation, it was not possible to find the necessary module.

So I solved it building the project in a high level path (such as D:\), to make sure the path sizes wouldn't be a problem.