# How to solve depedency with ndk-build in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I've Googled for a solution, but no one of them has solved my problem.

I have downloaded Tess-two and tried to ndk-build with downloaded ndk15r
from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
but nothing happens, same issue:

> Error:(687) Android NDK: Module pngt depends on undefined modules: z
> Error:(700) *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to >allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.
> Error:Execution failed for task ':tess-two:ndkClean'.
>
> Process 'command '/Users/archimedia/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I've tried also to ignore this error when from terminal I'm gone in tess-two directory, and I've typed "ndk-build", and I've imported the project directly.
But my Android Studio console has logged same error.

How can I save my life???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined modules when switching to a newer version of android ndk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706917/undefined-modules-when-switching-to-a-newer-version-of-android-ndk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar (though not the same) error. I was able to fix it by downgrading `ndk-bundle` to `13b`.. You can get older versions [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html).

Just extract and copy to `$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle`.

Comment: I just had to down-vote this as the technology is moving forward (latest NDK is r16) and you're suggesting the opposite...

Comment: you mean facebook/reactnative needs to update their documentation. It is still recommending using ndk-bundle r10. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html

Answer (score 11):

You can also add `APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS := true` to the Application.mk file without downgrading the ndk.

See:
https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r14-beta1#ndk-build

Comment: This worked for me and didn't need to downgrade the ndk, just used the last one.

Comment: This should be approved answer :)
Add reference to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r14-beta1#ndk-build

Comment: Where is the Application.mk file in mac